# Can I search for Gmail contacts with "OR"

Tags: google-contacts

I would like to search my contacts in Gmail in the following manner: I would like to get all contacts that contain one of the words that I enter, e.g.:

```
"Doron OR Danny"
```

This should bring my contacts:

- doron@gmail.com
- danny@hotmail.com

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, but you have to remove those quotes or it'll search that sentence exactly.

A list of all the parameters on gmail search:
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en

Comment: This is incorrect and unhelpful. Gmail search only searches the messages in Gmail; it does not work on Google Contacts.